# Process list as a background process

Tags: command-line, background-process

```
abhigenie92@ubuntu:~$ (sleep 2; echo $BASH_SUBSHELL ;sleep 2)
1
abhigenie92@ubuntu:~$ (sleep 2; echo $BASH_SUBSHELL ;sleep 2)&
[1] 3297
abhigenie92@ubuntu:~$ 1

[1]+  Done                    ( sleep 2; echo $BASH_SUBSHELL; sleep 2 )
```

What happens when launch it as a background process, why don't I get the prompt back and I have to press `Enter`? In both cases it launches a child shell.

Comment: I don't understand your question, exactly? Do you mean how `bash` doesn't report that the job is done until the next prompt is displayed (whereas, for example, `zsh` does)?

Answer (score 2):

You ***got*** the prompt back (see the fifth line of your code block) —
and ***then*** you got the output.  You were still "at the shell prompt"
when you typed <kbd>Enter</kbd> the third time.

In theory, the shell could be programmed to reissue the prompt
when a background process terminates.  But

1. That wouldn't really be very helpful.  Your issue is that,
   when the background job did the `echo 1` and the `1` appeared on your terminal,
   your cursor went back to the left edge of the screen,
   and it became non-obvious that you were still "at the shell prompt". 
   And the foreground shell doesn't know
   when a background task writes to the screen.
2. Historically, the shell doesn't know when you're *typing* a command;
   it knows only when you type <kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
   (That may still be the case in some contexts.)  So the shell wouldn't know
   if you were in the middle of typing a third command

   ```
   (sleep 3; echo someth
   ```

   and it would be really confusing if you got a new shell prompt
   when you were in the middle of typing a command.